# Big O Notation - Two arrays removing inner array elements

Tags: big-o, notation

I am a little confused as to what the big O notation for an example like this (this is not a real programming language, just a quick example):

```
for each entry in arraylist1
    for each entry in arraylist2
       if condition met
          remove element from arraylist2
```

Even if this code have two loops I don't think it is O(n^2), since for each entry I can remove n elements, which will reduce the number of iterations drastically.

I usually use this kind of algorithm when I already processed or found the elements on the array for a given criteria but need to continue.

Edit: Now that I think of, the worst case scenario would only remove all elements on the last iteration of the first loop resulting in a "true" O(n^2).

Comment: It's not `O(n^2)` since the inner loop depends on a different input variable than the first. This seems like it would be `O(n*k)`, where the worst case is the length of the first input * the input of the second input: if `n` was 10 and `k` was `20`, then at worst there would be `200` iterations, where `n == arraylist1.size()` and `k == arraylist2.size()`

Comment: This might be written as `O(mn)`. [Q&A on CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/is-omn-considered-linear-or-quadratic-growth).